# Adldap::auth()->attempt(username, password) return always false

Tags: laravel, active-directory, ldap

Laravel Version: 5.8
Adldap2-Laravel Version: 6.0
PHP Version: 7.1.3
LDAP Type: ActiveDirectory

Hi, The credentials are correct but i can't pass the login with them. Adlap::auth()->attempt() return always false.

```
$user_format = env('LDAP_USER_FORMAT', 'cn=%s,dc=corp,dc=org');
$userdn = sprintf($user_format, $username);

 if(Adldap::auth()->attempt($userdn, $request->password , true)) {
           return redirect('/home');
 } else {
            dd($userdn);
 }
```

config/ldap_auth.php

```
'connection' => env('LDAP_CONNECTION', 'default'),
'provider' => Adldap\Laravel\Auth\DatabaseUserProvider::class,
'model' => App\User::class,
'rules' => [
    Adldap\Laravel\Validation\Rules\DenyTrashed::class,
],
'identifiers' => [
    'ldap' => [
        'locate_users_by' => 'userprincipalname',
        'bind_users_by' => 'distinguishedname',
    ],

    'database' => [
        'username_column' => 'username',
    ],

    'windows' => [
        'locate_users_by' => 'samaccountname'
    ],
],
'login_fallback' => env('LDAP_LOGIN_FALLBACK', false),
'usernames' => [
    'ldap' => 'userprincipalname', // was just 'userprincipalname'
    'eloquent' => 'username', // was 'email'
],
'sync_attributes' => [
    'username' => 'userprincipalname',
    'name' => 'cn',
],

'logging' => [
    'enabled' => env('LDAP_LOGGING', true),
```

Comment: what if you directly put value here `attempt('username', 'password', true)` ?

Comment: I tried. I wronged username with prefix and suffix. 
Now my error is: 
Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::__construct() must be an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider, null given, called in /var/www/DATI/pmi/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/AuthManager.php on line 125

Answer (score -1):

I resolved.

Username format was wrong. I didn't need this information.

```
$user_format = env('LDAP_USER_FORMAT', 'cn=%s,dc=corp,dc=org');
$userdn = sprintf($user_format, $username);

 if(Adldap::auth()->attempt($userdn, $request->password , true)) {
```

Now, I take value entered in form. In my case name.surname

```
if(Adldap::auth()->attempt($request->username, $request->password , true)) {
```